# How to tidy the equation in overleaf

Tags: equations, overleaf

I would like to write two equations (R3 and R4) in overleaf.

[image: expected equations]
Since I use a template which are in two column format, the equations become untidy as in the screenshot.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:R3}
R_3(i) = 
 \begin{cases} 
  (q_i.c_i + (1-q_i)p_i + (n+1)w + nv)(\frac{q_i}{m_i-z_i} +\frac{(1-q_i)}{m_i-z_i})  & \text{if } i \geq (n-1) \\
  (q_n.p_n + (1-q_n)c_n + (n+1)w + nv)(\frac{q_n}{m_n-z_n} +\frac{(1-q_n)}{m_n-z_n})       & \text{if } i = n
 \end{cases}\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:R4}
R_4(i) = 
 \begin{cases} 
  (q_i.p_i + (1-q_i)c_i + (n+3)w + (n+2)v)(\frac{q_i}{z_i+1} +\frac{(1-q_i)}{z_i+1})  & \text{if } i \geq (n-1) \\
  (q_n.c_n + (1-q_n)p_n + (n+3)w + (n+2)v)(\frac{q_n}{z_n+1} +\frac{(1-q_n)}{z_n+1})       & \text{if } i = n
 \end{cases}\end{equation}
```

Then, here is the preview.
[image: preview]

Do you have any idea how to make these equations tidier ?
I am thinking to make the font smaller however I am not sure what to do.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the TEX.SE. community. What is the minimal complete example to reproduce your screenshot? Please can you glue in your question?

Comment: It is probably better to rephrase especially since you are working in two columns and thus have much more limited space.

Comment: Hi @Sebastiano, I added the expected equation on this page. Is that what you meant? 
Hi Daleif, what is meant by "to rephrase"? Any example, perhaps?

Thank you.

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: @NicholasTI A minimal working example it is as the code of Clara. Starting from \documentclass to end to \end{document}.

Comment: Hi @egreg, it is \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## wrap and small fontsize

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:R3}
\small
R_3(i) =
\begin{cases}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={l},colsep={0pt}}(q_i.c_i + (1-q_i)p_i + (n+1)w + nv) \\ \times(\frac{q_i}{m_i-z_i} +\frac{(1-q_i)}{m_i-z_i})\end{tblr} & \text{if } i \geq (n-1) \\
\begin{tblr}{colspec={l},colsep={0pt}}(q_n.p_n + (1-q_n)c_n + (n+1)w + nv) \\ \times(\frac{q_n}{m_n-z_n} +\frac{(1-q_n)}{m_n-z_n})\end{tblr} & \text{if } i = n
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:R4}
\footnotesize
R_4(i) =
\begin{cases}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={l},colsep={0pt}}(q_i.p_i + (1-q_i)c_i + (n+3)w + (n+2)v) \\ \times(\frac{q_i}{z_i+1} +\frac{(1-q_i)}{z_i+1})\end{tblr} & \text{if } i \geq (n-1) \\
\begin{tblr}{colspec={l},colsep={0pt}}(q_n.c_n + (1-q_n)p_n + (n+3)w + (n+2)v) \\ \times(\frac{q_n}{z_n+1} +\frac{(1-q_n)}{z_n+1})\end{tblr} & \text{if } i = n
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\par\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

## double column equation

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{strip}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:R3}
R_3(i) =
\begin{cases}
(q_i.c_i + (1-q_i)p_i + (n+1)w + nv)(\frac{q_i}{m_i-z_i} +\frac{(1-q_i)}{m_i-z_i}) & \text{if } i \geq (n-1) \\
(q_n.p_n + (1-q_n)c_n + (n+1)w + nv)(\frac{q_n}{m_n-z_n} +\frac{(1-q_n)}{m_n-z_n}) & \text{if } i = n
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:R4}
R_4(i) =
\begin{cases}
(q_i.p_i + (1-q_i)c_i + (n+3)w + (n+2)v)(\frac{q_i}{z_i+1} +\frac{(1-q_i)}{z_i+1}) & \text{if } i \geq (n-1) \\
(q_n.c_n + (1-q_n)p_n + (n+3)w + (n+2)v)(\frac{q_n}{z_n+1} +\frac{(1-q_n)}{z_n+1}) & \text{if } i = n
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{strip}
\lipsum[4-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Typesetting such big formulas in two-column format often requires some comprimise.

Here the compromise is to split the longish parts and give up with `cases`, so pushing the conditions under the longer top part.

Using `newtxmath` not only ensures consistency between text and math fonts, but also makes the math narrower.

*Note.* `showframe` and `lipsum` are used only for debugging. The former adds the frames as seen in the picture.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-3]
\begin{align}
\label{eq:R3}
\hspace{-0.5em}
R_3(i) &=
  \left\lbrace
  \begin{aligned}
    &\mathmakebox[0.5\columnwidth][l]{(q_i.c_i + (1-q_i)p_i + (n+1)w + nv)} \\[0.5ex]
    &\cdot\left(\frac{q_i}{m_i-z_i} +\frac{1-q_i}{m_i-z_i}\right)
    && \text{if } i \geq n-1
  \\[2ex]
    &\mathmakebox[0.5\columnwidth][l]{(q_n.p_n + (1-q_n)c_n + (n+1)w + nv)} \\[0.5ex]
    &\cdot\left(\frac{q_n}{m_n-z_n} +\frac{1-q_n}{m_n-z_n}\right)
    && \text{if } i = n
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
\\
\label{eq:R4}
\hspace{-0.5em}
R_4(i) &=
  \left\lbrace
  \begin{aligned}
    &\mathmakebox[0.5\columnwidth][l]{(q_i.p_i + (1-q_i)c_i + (n+3)w + (n+2)v)} \\[0.5ex]
    &\cdot\left(\frac{q_i}{z_i+1} +\frac{1-q_i}{z_i+1}\right)
    && \text{if } i \geq n-1
  \\[2ex]
    &\mathmakebox[0.5\columnwidth][l]{(q_n.c_n + (1-q_n)p_n + (n+3)w + (n+2)v)} \\[0.5ex]
    &\cdot\left(\frac{q_n}{z_n+1} +\frac{1-q_n}{z_n+1}\right)
    && \text{if } i = n
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{align}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @egred, both notations are well written, however there is additional text: Lorem ipsum... same as in your screenshot. What should I do to delete the unnecessarily text? Thank you.

Comment: There are missing "are" between two equations in the systeme. Can you see the image in the question?

Comment: @NicholasTI Just remove the `\lipsum` commands. I removed the “and” between the cases, because it's not customary to have it: the brace already tells the reader about it.

Comment: Thank you @egred

Comment: Hi  @clara, do you mind taking a look at this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678591/288908 , please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest that you load the `mathtools` package -- a superset of the `amsmath` package -- and employ `\mathrlap` wrappers and `dcases` environments, both provided by the `mathtools` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{mathtools}   % for '\mathrlap' macro and 'dcases' env.
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman text and math font clones
\usepackage{lipsum}      % filler text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] % a paragraph of filler text
\begin{align} 
R_3(i) &=
 \begin{dcases}
  \mathrlap{\bigl(q_i c_i + (1-q_i)p_i + (n+1)w + nv\bigr)} \\
  \quad\times\biggl(\frac{q_i}{m_i-z_i} +\frac{1-q_i}{m_i-z_i}\biggr)
  & \text{if $1\le i<n$} \\[1ex]
  \mathrlap{\bigl(q_n p_n + (1-q_n)c_n + (n+1)w + nv)} \\
  \quad\times\biggl(\frac{q_n}{m_n-z_n} +\frac{1-q_n}{m_n-z_n}\biggr)
  & \text{if $i=n$}
 \end{dcases} \label{eq:R3} \\[1.5ex]
R_4(i) &=
 \begin{dcases}
  \mathrlap{\bigl(q_i p_i + (1-q_i)c_i + (n+3)w + (n+2)v\bigr)} \\
  \quad\times\biggl(\frac{q_i}{z_i+1} +\frac{1-q_i}{z_i+1}\biggr)
  & \text{if $1\le i<n$} \\[1ex]
  \mathrlap{\bigl(q_n c_n + (1-q_n)p_n + (n+3)w + (n+2)v\bigr)}\\
  \quad\times\biggl(\frac{q_n}{z_n+1} +\frac{1-q_n}{z_n+1}\biggr)
  & \text{if $i=n$}
 \end{dcases} \label{eq:R4}
\end{align}
\lipsum % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Mico, how to delete the additional text which is not in English (Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...) when I used the given code? Thank you.

Comment: @NicholasTI - Just omit the directives `\lipsum[1]` and `\lipsum`.

Comment: Hi, do you mind taking a look at the new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678591/288908 , please?