# How to write long inequalities in a corollary in a two-column document

Tags: equations, ieeetran

I would like to write down this Corollary. It contains two inequalities, as shown in the following screenshot. I use the two-column `IEEEtran` document class in overleaf -- currently with TeX Live 2022.

[image: original]

As an illustration, the expected result is similar like this, even though the equations (1) and (2) do not seem neat.

[image: expected 2 columns]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{corollary}\label{Corollary:new_seq}
Supposing that $i^{\ast} = argmax_i R_3(i)$ and $i^{\ast\ast} = argmax_i R_4(i)$ for all   $i=1,\ldots,n$, if $max (R_3(i),R_4(i)) \geq max(R_5(A^{\prime}),R_6(A^{\prime\prime}))$ in a serial configuration, then the new sequence is optimal when one of the following constraints is fulfilled.

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:corollary_i}
    max_{i^{\ast} =1,...,n} (q_i^{\ast}\cdot p_i^{\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast})c_i^{\ast} \quad  \forall i^{\ast}\geq(n-1), q_i^{\ast}\cdot c_i^{\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast})p_i^{\ast} \quad   \text{for $i^{\ast} = n$}) \geq (n-1)w + nv
    \end{equation}
 
    \item
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:corollary_ii}
    max_{i^{\ast\ast} =1,...,n} (q_i^{\ast\ast}\cdot p_i^{\ast\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast\ast})c_i^{\ast\ast} \quad  \forall i^{\ast\ast}\geq(n-1), q_i^{\ast\ast}\cdot c_i^{\ast\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast\ast})p_i^{\ast\ast} \quad  \text{for $i^{\ast} = n$}) \geq (n+1)w + (n+2)v
    \end{equation}    
\end{enumerate}
\end{corollary}
\end{document}
```

However, both of the equations (i) and (ii) surpasses the column as follows.

[image]

Could anyone recommend what to do with the code, please?
If you have other options to make a more neat writing, kindly let me know.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable. The environment `corollary` is undefined and in line 18 you are probably missing a `}`. 
Off-topic: I'd strongly recommend to use `\max` instead of `max`. The same applies for `argmax`, but you will have to define `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}` in your preamble for that.

Comment: @Οὖτις, may I know how to make the MWE compilable and define the environment of corollary, please?

Comment: Your document should be compilable as is, so it should not result in any errors when I copy your code and compile it. Here, you need to add `\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}` or something similar to your preamble to define the environment. When I wrote my first comment, the code was also missing the `\end{corollary}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't tag the inequalities with both an enumeration label and an equation label. Since you need the enumeration label anyway, I'd dispense with the equation label. In the code below, I set up the enumeration so that items can be cross-referenced easily.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsmath} % amsmath is loaded automatically by mathtools
\DeclareMathOperator{\argmax}{argmax}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{corollary}\label{Corollary:new_seq}
Suppose that $i^{\ast} = \argmax_i R_3(i)$ and 
$i^{\ast\ast} = \argmax_i R_4(i)$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. 
If $\max (R_3(i),R_4(i)) \geq \max(R_5(A'),R_6(A''))$ 
in a serial configuration, then the new sequence is 
optimal if one of the following constraints is 
ful\-filled.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textup{C.\roman*)},
                  ref= C.\roman*,
                  left=0pt, align=left]
\item \label{item:corollary_i}
\parbox[t]{0.8\columnwidth}{\raggedright$ 
    \max\limits_{i^{\ast} =1,\dots,n}
    \bigl\{
    q_i^{\ast} p_i^{\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast})c_i^{\ast} 
    \textup{ for all $i^{\ast}\leq n-1$},\allowbreak 
    q_i^{\ast} c_i^{\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast})p_i^{\ast} 
    \textup{ for $i^{\ast} = n$}
    \bigr\} 
    \geq (n-1)w + nv$}

\bigskip
\item \label{item:corollary_ii}
\parbox[t]{0.87\columnwidth}{\raggedright$
    \max\limits_{i^{\ast\ast} =1,\dots,n}
    \bigl\{
    q_i^{\ast\ast} p_i^{\ast\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast\ast}) c_i^{\ast\ast} 
    \textup{ for all $i^{\ast\ast}\leq n-1$},\allowbreak
     q_i^{\ast\ast} c_i^{\ast\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast\ast})p_i^{\ast\ast} 
    \textup{ for $i^{\ast} = n$}
    \bigr\} 
    \geq (n+1)w + (n+2)v$}
\end{enumerate}
\end{corollary}

If one of the constraints \ref{item:corollary_i} or 
\ref{item:corollary_ii} is fulfilled, \dots
\end{document}
```